# Перегрузка операторов для возведения в степень

Tags: c#, .net

Можно ли на шарпе перегрузить оператор или создать что-то для возведения в степень наподобие `3^2` или `(3)2` ну или `3**2`?

Comment: Для возведения в степерь можно заюзать статический метод класса Math - Pow
Math.Pow(3, 2)

Comment: Это не кошерно. Я хочу перегрузить оператор инта. Как метод, только оператор.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8edha89s.aspx изучайте.А вот создать свой оператор, увы, не удастся. Во всяком случае мне не удалось.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете переопределить уже существующий оператор для тех типов, для которых он определён. И вы не можете придумать новый символ, обозначающий оператор, вы должны перегружать существующий оператор.

Также вы не можете перегрузить оператор, если *ни один из операндов не является вашим типом*. Например, вы не можете определить оператор `^` для строки и числа. Однако, вот такое можно:

```
class X
{
    int v;
    public X(int v) { this.v = v; }
    public static implicit operator X (int i) { return new X(i); }
    static public double operator ^ (X x, int y) { return Math.Pow(x.v, y); }
}
```

При этом `(X)5 ^ 2` выдаст 25.

Comment: Не советую Вам использовать переопределение оператора ^ для возведения в степень. Это не очевидно и вообще неправильно.

В учебных целях поиграться можно, но не более.

Comment: @syler: А почему мне-то? Так в вопросе сформулировано.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
SomeClass a = new SomeClass() { Var = 2 };
SomeClass b = new SomeClass() { Var = 2 };
SomeClass c = new SomeClass();

c = a ^ b;

class SomeClass
{
    public int Var
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static SomeClass operator ^(SomeClass a, SomeClass b)
    {
        SomeClass tmpClass  = new SomeClass();
        tmpClass.Var = (int)Math.Pow(a.Var, b.Var);

        return tmpClass;
    }
}
```